# Why does a shared object fail if it has extra symbols compared to the original

Tags: shared-libraries, embedded-linux, glibc

I have a stripped ld.so that I want to replace with the unstripped version (so that valgrind works). I have ensured that I have the same version of glib and the cross compiler.

I have compiled the shared object, calling 'file' on it shows that it is compiled correctly (the only difference with the original being the 'unstripped' and being about 15% bigger). Unfortunately, it then causes a kernel panic (unable to init) on start up. Stripping the newly compiled .so, readelf-ing it and diff-ing it with the original, shows that there were extra symbols in the new version of the .so . All of the old symbols were still present, so what I don't understand is why the kernel panics with those extra symbols there.

I would expect the extra symbols to have no affect on the kernel start up, as they should never be called, so why do I get a kernel panic?

NB: To be clear - I will still need to investigate why there are extra symbols, but my question is about why these unused symbols cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel (assuming Linux) doesn't depend on or use `ld.so` in any way, shape or form. The reason it panics is most likely that it can't exec any of the user-level programs (such as `/bin/init` and `/bin/sh`), which do use `ld.so`.

As to why your `init` doesn't like your new `ld.so`, it's hard to tell. One common mistake is to try to replace `ld.so` with the contents of `/usr/lib/debug/ld-X.Y.so`. While that file looks like it's not much different from the original `/lib/ld-X.Y.so`, it is in fact *very* different, and can't be used to replace the original, only to debug the original (`/usr/lib/debug/ld-X.Y.so` usually contains only debug sections, but none of code and data sections of `/lib/ld-X.Y.so`, and so attempts to run it usually cause immediate `SIGSEGV`).

Perhaps you can set up a `chroot`, mimicking your embedded environment, and run `/bin/ls` in it? The error (or a core dump) this will produce will likely tell you what's wrong with your `ld.so`.

Comment: Hmm, I think I'm making this common mistake. I'll try the chroot option to determine exactly what the root cause of the problem is.

Comment: Any update? I am working on a slightly related problem and would like to know how it is going.